Stimulated Raman Scattering mechanism in laser plasma interaction
I have questions about the stimulated Raman parametric instability (SRS) that occurs during the interaction between a laser pulse and a plasma. What does the terms "parametric" and "stimulated" mean? What is the physical mechanism behind this instability?
Thanks again.
